# Calibri font family is not applying for react application in IOS Browsers

Tags: html, css, reactjs, font-face

Hi I am using calibri fonts in my application,It is working fine in windows in chrome browser, But not working in IOS safari and chrome browsers. I have added the .ttf and .woff2 files in project itself in fonts folder and added font face in index.css
below is the css file.

```
body {
  font-family: 'Calibri', sans-serif;
}

code {
  font-family:'Calibri',source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
    monospace;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Calibri";
  src: local("Calibri"),
   url("./assets/fonts/calibri-bold.ttf") format("truetype"),
   url("./assets/fonts/calibri-bold.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal
 }

 @font-face {
  font-family: "Calibri";
  src: local("Calibri"),
   url("./assets/fonts/calibri-regular.ttf") format("truetype"),
   url("./assets/fonts/calibri-regular.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-weight:500;
  font-style: normal;
 }
 @font-face {
  font-family: "Calibri";
  src: local("Calibri"),
   url("./assets/fonts/calibri-bold-italic.ttf") format("truetype"),
   url("./assets/fonts/calibri-bold-italic.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-weight:bold;
  font-style: italic;
 }
 
 @font-face {
  font-family: "Calibri";
  src: local("Calibri"),
   url("./assets/fonts/calibri-italic.ttf") format("truetype"),
   url("./assets/fonts/calibri-italic.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-weight:500;
  font-style: italic;
 }
```

Please let me know what i need to change.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that those urls are correct?

Comment: @AHaworth yes it is, this font files are in my project fonts folder